# cant change PS1 on zsh, trying to find the configuration file

Tags: linux, shell, zsh

Good Afternoon,

A while back i had a friend show me a cool template to change the command prompt look of my zsh. I forgot the installation process and the name of the file. it wasnt oh.my.zsh.

the PS1 in ~/.zshrc has no effect on the command prompt however my aliases still work from the ~/.zshrc

Does anyone know a way to find the file that is managing my command prompt template?

UPDATE: 
this is my current .zshrc file. I am trying to get oh-my-zsh configured right now but the previous

Previous config file:

```
PS1="%{%F{red}%}%n%{%f%}@%{%F{green}%}%m %{%F{yellow}%}%~ 
%{$%f%}%% "


#alias for account

alias conPi="ssh -p1989 user@site.com"
alias joinIRC="bash ~/SHELLSCRIPTS/joinIRC.sh"
```

Current config File

```
# If you come from bash you might have to change your $PATH.
# export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH

# Path to your oh-my-zsh installation.
export ZSH=$HOME/.oh-my-zsh

# Set name of the theme to load. Optionally, if you set this to "random"
# it'll load a random theme each time that oh-my-zsh is loaded.
# See https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/wiki/Themes
ZSH_THEME="robbyrussell"

# Set list of themes to load
# Setting this variable when ZSH_THEME=random
# cause zsh load theme from this variable instead of
# looking in ~/.oh-my-zsh/themes/
# An empty array have no effect
# ZSH_THEME_RANDOM_CANDIDATES=( "robbyrussell" "agnoster" )

# Uncomment the following line to use case-sensitive completion.
# CASE_SENSITIVE="true"

# Uncomment the following line to use hyphen-insensitive completion. Case
# sensitive completion must be off. _ and - will be interchangeable.
# HYPHEN_INSENSITIVE="true"

# Uncomment the following line to disable bi-weekly auto-update checks.
# DISABLE_AUTO_UPDATE="true"

# Uncomment the following line to change how often to auto-update (in days).
# export UPDATE_ZSH_DAYS=13

# Uncomment the following line to disable colors in ls.
# DISABLE_LS_COLORS="true"

# Uncomment the following line to disable auto-setting terminal title.
# DISABLE_AUTO_TITLE="true"

# Uncomment the following line to enable command auto-correction.
# ENABLE_CORRECTION="true"

# Uncomment the following line to display red dots whilst waiting for completion.
# COMPLETION_WAITING_DOTS="true"

# Uncomment the following line if you want to disable marking untracked files
# under VCS as dirty. This makes repository status check for large repositories
# much, much faster.
# DISABLE_UNTRACKED_FILES_DIRTY="true"

# Uncomment the following line if you want to change the command execution time
# stamp shown in the history command output.
# The optional three formats: "mm/dd/yyyy"|"dd.mm.yyyy"|"yyyy-mm-dd"
# HIST_STAMPS="mm/dd/yyyy"

# Would you like to use another custom folder than $ZSH/custom?
# ZSH_CUSTOM=/path/to/new-custom-folder

# Which plugins would you like to load? (plugins can be found in ~/.oh-my-zsh/plugins/*)
# Custom plugins may be added to ~/.oh-my-zsh/custom/plugins/
# Example format: plugins=(rails git textmate ruby lighthouse)
# Add wisely, as too many plugins slow down shell startup.
plugins=(
  git
)

source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh

# User configuration

# export MANPATH="/usr/local/man:$MANPATH"

# You may need to manually set your language environment
# export LANG=en_US.UTF-8

# Preferred editor for local and remote sessions
# if [[ -n $SSH_CONNECTION ]]; then
#   export EDITOR='vim'
# else
#   export EDITOR='mvim'
# fi

# Compilation flags
# export ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64"

# ssh
# export SSH_KEY_PATH="~/.ssh/rsa_id"

# Set personal aliases, overriding those provided by oh-my-zsh libs,
# plugins, and themes. Aliases can be placed here, though oh-my-zsh
# users are encouraged to define aliases within the ZSH_CUSTOM folder.
# For a full list of active aliases, run `alias`.
#
# Example aliases
# alias zshconfig="mate ~/.zshrc"
# alias ohmyzsh="mate ~/.oh-my-zsh"
```

Comment: It *should* have an effect. Does `PS1` change when you open a new shell? You can simply type `zsh` or open a new tab in your terminal emulator.

Comment: Paste the content of your .zshrc please

Comment: I've updated my post to include both my current ~/.zshrc file and the one prior to trying to change it to oh-my-zsh today.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk no, ive tried restarting the laptop and opening new terminals. the prompt stays the same and neither reflects the new config file nor the one prior.

Comment: @TimothyKing: I can't see `PS1` set anywhere in `.zshrc` you posted, there are also no aliases.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk yeah, i was concerned about posting my aliases because they contain a domain i own but i censored it. You can see my old config file in all its glory now.  The new file apparently pulls the PS1 from that template call at the top.

Comment: I see. I added `PS1="%{%F{red}%}%n%{%f%}@%{%F{green}%}%m %{%F{yellow}%}%~ 
%{$%f%}%% "` to my `~/.zshrc` and it works. Where is `PS1` defined in your current setup, is it in `$HOME/.oh-my-zsh`?

Comment: You can also run `PS1="%{%F{red}%}%n%{%f%}@%{%F{green}%}%m %{%F{yellow}%}%~ 
%{$%f%}%% "
` in your current session to temporarily set a new prompt and check if it works. If it does, it must also work when sourced from `~/.zshrc`.

Comment: in .oh-my-zsh/themes/robby* there is a "PROMPT=" but its calling cyan and green. definitely not the one im looking at right now. that is my problem. i have no idea where its getting its configuration from, however those aliases work.

Comment: actually that doesnt work... ive tried changing PS1 in the current terminal and that doesnt work. it continues to use the one in place now... this is weird huh?

Comment: Not necessarily, I also experience that because I use
[`liquidprompt`](https://github.com/nojhan/liquidprompt) that sets
`PROMPT_COMMAND` and always overwrites `PS1`. Try unsetting
`PROMPT_COMMAND` before changing `PS1`.

Comment: Hmm, I've just learned that `PROMPT_COMMAND` is a `bash` thing, I don't know what's the `zsh` equivalent.

Comment: i assume that "PROMPT_COMMAND" is an environmental variable. It doesnt appear to have a value right now. I unset it but still nothing.

Comment: I said it's a `bash` thing. Does it work if you only have `PS1="%{%F{red}%}%n%{%f%}@%{%F{green}%}%m %{%F{yellow}%}%~ 
%{$%f%}%% "
` in your `~/.zshrc`?

Comment: nope, I appreciate your help. Im going to have to find out what can overwrite the PS1 in a zsh enviroment

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

When `$ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh` is sourced, it uses the value of `ZSH_THEME` to load a configuration file that usually configures your prompt (the default theme `robbyrussell` certainly does). Any changes you attempt to make to the prompt before that get overwritten. If you want to make any changes, you need to do so *after* oh-my-zsh makes its changes. Or, as it intends, create your own theme that configures your prompt, and use your theme instead of `robbyrussell`.

Note that there are also several hook functions that `zsh` will call at various times. The two that are most likely to be overwriting your changes to the prompt are `chpwd` and `precmd`; these and others are documented in `zshmisc`.

Comment: But OP said he cannot change `PS1` even when in interactive shell - there is something similar to `PROMPT_COMMAND` from `bash` that overwrites his `PS1` every time.

Comment: Ah, right. There are actually quite a few places this could happen. The two most likely are the `chpwd` and `precmd` hooks

Comment: sorry i never responded last night. turns out i was using grml. I had to remove grml-zsh-config from my system before i could use a .zshrc for changing the PS1.